# Https simple get request

Tags: android, ssl, httpurlconnection

I am trying to make a get https request as follows:

```
{
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpsURLConnection  connection = (HttspURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

        connection.connect();

        int responseCode =  connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
            stringResponse = response;
        } else {


            stringResponse = "NONET";

            Log.e(Constants.tag, requestURL + " HTTP ERROR: "
                    + responseCode + "\n" +  connection.getResponseMessage());

        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException net) {


        Log.e(Constants.tag, requestURL + " HTTP ERROR", net);
        stringResponse = "NONET";

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException time) {


        Log.e(Constants.tag, requestURL + " HTTP ERROR", time);
        stringResponse = "NONET";

    } catch (SSLHandshakeException e) {


        Log.e(Constants.tag, requestURL + " HTTP ERROR", e);
        stringResponse = null;


    } catch (Exception e) {


        Log.e(Constants.tag, requestURL + " HTTP ERROR", e);
        stringResponse = null;


    } finally {

        received.set(true);


    }

    return response;
}
```

If the URL is http works correctly, but if the url is https I always get the following error.

> E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f80a06f80 cert_verify_callback
>   x509_store_ctx=0x7f6afc02d8 arg=0x0 E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f80a06f80
>   cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain
>   authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
>   E/app tag: https://api(...)/all HTTP ERROR:
>   404                                                         Not Found

I tried from the Android device browser enter the https url and the api is displayed correctly. (Is json api)

Comment: you need to use HttpsURLConnection  for creating connection.

Comment: I made that change and the result is the same. I edit the code with the changes.

Comment: you have to handle certificates also. Please see my answer for same.

Comment: Does it gives you answer for same. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a function for all POST/PUT/GET request to HTTPS server

a. You have to Self-signed certificate stuff to be handled. Please include that for sure.

b. You have to tell which type of content-Type to want to send to server.

c. Depending upon server configuration. What ever request you are sending to server check through POSTMAN or curl command to verify if is working, before working on Android request.

Here is my sample code for same.

```
 public String createConnection (String urlS, String methodInvoked,String patchBody, String postBody,String putBody){
            URL url ;
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String toBeReturned="";
            try {
                url = new URL(urlS);
                 HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override

                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
                            return myTrustedAnchors;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);


            HttpsURLConnection  connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
            connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            connection.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);


            if (patchBody  != null ){
                Log.i(TAG, " createConnection with PATH with body" );
                connection.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
                connection.setRequestProperty("data",patchBody);
                connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                dStream.writeBytes(patchBody);
                dStream.flush();
                dStream.close();
            }
            if (methodInvoked.equalsIgnoreCase("PATCH") && patchBody == null ){
                Log.i(TAG, " createConnection with PATH without body" );
                connection.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
//              connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
//              connection.setDoOutput(true);
            }
            if (postBody != null){
                Log.i(TAG, " createConnection with POST with body" );
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                dStream.writeBytes(postBody);
                dStream.flush();
                dStream.close();
            }

            if (methodInvoked.equalsIgnoreCase("POST") && postBody == null ){
                Log.i(TAG, " createConnection with POST without body" );
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                //connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            }

            if (putBody != null){
                Log.i(TAG, " createConnection with PUT with body" );
                connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                dStream.writeBytes(putBody);
                dStream.flush();
                dStream.close();
            }



            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            InputStream in= null;
            if(responseCode >= HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
            {   

                in = connection.getErrorStream();
                br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null; 
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                 String toBeReturned_1 = sb.toString();
                 Log.i(TAG, " createConnetion error received " +  responseCode  + "  " + toBeReturned_1) ;

            }
            else{


                br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null; 
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                toBeReturned = sb.toString();


            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                if (br!=null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        Log.i(TAG, " createConnetion  finally returned" +  toBeReturned );
        return toBeReturned; 
    }
```

By default createconnection function will be doing GET request

For GET Request call it like this :-

```
String urlS_ = "https://google.com"; // your URI
String methodInvoked = "GET"
createConnection (urlS_, methodInvoked,null, null,null)
```

For POST Request call it like this :-

```
String urlS_ = "https://gmail.com"; // your URI
String methodInvoked = "POST"
String postBody = postbody_; // Create a postbody_ which  you want to create 
createConnection (urlS_, methodInvoked,null, postBody ,null)
```

You can trim function according to your needs